# cdecl и extern "C"

Tags: dll

Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли я понимаю следующее.

- `extern "C"` - отключает искажение имен, например, при экспортировании функций в `DLL`;
- `cdecl` - описывает технические особенности вызова.

То есть, если я экспортирую функции в `DLL`, мне нужно использовать и `extern "C"`, и `cdecl`?

Comment: Да, все верно..

Answer (score 2):

`extern "C"` отключает искажение имен и обеспечивает возможность вызова функции из программы, написанной на C. А также из других программ, которые могут вызывать API: .NET PInvoke, Assembly, Delphy итд.

Для клиента на C++ `extern "C"` не обязтельно. Без этого объявления можно использовать function overloading. `extern "C"` ислючает эту возможность.

`cdecl` это станартный Calling Convention, подходящий для всех клиентов. Можно использовать другие конвенции, если клиент их понимает. Например конвенция WinAPI - `stdcall`

Answer (score 1):

Самое главное отличие - стратегия передачи и обработки параметров

Зачастую это пользователю конечно безразлично, но тем не менее об этом надо помнить

```
__cdecl - Caller Pushes parameters on the stack, in reverse order (right to left)
__stdcall - Caller Pushes parameters on the stack, in reverse order (right to left)
__fastcall  - Caller Stored in registers, then pushed on stack
```